# I got this multiple errors about BuildFailedException Burst Complier 1.6 when i try to build and run?

Tags: unity

[image: Even googling it wont help. Please advice]

I reinstalling Desktop Development under visual studio attachment etc. Even put build it on the same folder where I created this same game.

Comment: Error messages should be shared as text, not as images. This improves search hits for your question, so other users with relevant experience can find it.

Comment: The specific error looks like a file permissions problem. I've encountered something similar when developing a shared project from multiple user accounts - some files got created with exclusive access rights for only one of the users. Forcibly setting the file permissions on the project folder and recursing to all its contents solved my problem in that case - you may want to investigate whether a similar issue is at play here.